# Echo multiple tasks if a common function exists

Tags: php, functions, query

How can I echo multiple tasks if a common WordPress function exists.

For example, I want to reduce the following:

```
<?php if (function_exists ('pluginName')) echo someName (1); ?>
<?php if (function_exists ('pluginName')) echo someName (2); ?>
<?php if (function_exists ('pluginName')) echo someName (3); ?>
<?php if (function_exists ('pluginName')) echo someName (4); ?>
```

into a single query like this:

```
<?php if (function_exists ('pluginName')) echo someName (1); someName (2); someName (3); someName (4); ?>
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Brackets may help. See [second example](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) - the one with multiple statements.

Comment: Something like this? -> <?php if (function_exists ('pluginName')) { echo someName (7); echo someName (8); echo someName (9); } ?>

Comment: Yup, that'll do it.

Comment: Thank you good sir. Do add that as the answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Howdy_McGee mentioned in the comments, you can just wrapped the multiple commands you want to run within curly brackets like this:

```
<?php if (function_exists ('pluginName')) { echo someName (7); echo someName (8); echo someName (9); } ?>
```